# How to add and retrieve passwords without storing them on server

Tags: flask, encryption, password-encryption

I am working on something that is similar to that of which I can keep track of a users instagram analytics.

The issue I'm having is, I need to be able to log in to my users instagram account, however I don't want to store the passwords as that is a privacy concern.

What do I do in this situation? In my app, the users would have to input their instagram username and password, and I would need to be able to access those so I can use their account to get the analytics etc, but how do I do this without ever having to store their passwords?

After doing some research, I'm getting recommended something similar to the way lastpass does it, they provide you a master key that encrypts all your passwords, and only if you can provide that master key will the passwords be decrypted.

Is this the approach I should take? If so how should I get started on it, by the way my app is using a flask backend with mongo database

Comment: You don't need the users' passwords: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: @Peter, authorizing them only gives me access to what the API can provide, for my purpose I need to be able to login to the user accounts

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER take credentials from your users, that in itself is a serious privacy concern, even if you store them "securely". You shouldn't be able to log in to your users accounts. Forget that lastpass suggestion.

Instead, you should ask them for permissions to take the data you need (analytics etc.), instagram should have an API that allows you to ask for those permissions.

Comment: Yes that would be ideal, the problem is then I am dependent on the API, and that would not allow me to serve the purpose of my app. I would need to be able to login to the account somehow, is there a safe way to do that?

Comment: As far as I know there is no legal way to login to other people's accounts. You should probably dig deeper into the API and what it can provide for you. What information were you expecting to get after logging in?